# "Its color is brown" vs "It is brown in color" describing nouns

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, syntactic-analysis

I was wondering what the difference between these two similar ways of describing a noun is.

> Its color is brown.

or

> It is brown in color.

If they are both proper usage please explain to me which one is use more often. Thank you.

Comment: Why not make it easy for yourself and just say *"It's brown"*?

Comment: And not, notice, _Its brown_.

Comment: Notwithstanding all that, I think it should be pointed out that both your suggestions are grammatically correct, except that in the second example 'It's' should contain an apostrophe.

Comment: And the reason for that gratuitous inaudible apostrophe is that _its_ in _Its color_ is a possessive pronoun, whereas _it's_ in _It's brown_ is a contraction of _it_ and the predicate adjective auxiliary verb _is_. They are two completely different grammatical constructions -- _its color_ is a noun phrase, while _it's brown_ is a clause; hence the apostrophe, in writing only. In speech, of course, their pronounced the same, and theirs never any problem, with or without the inaudible apo'strophe.

Comment: You should also include the sentences in the main body of the question when writing out your question, even if they are included in teh title, to help avoid confusion.  But both sentences are gramatically correct, and perfectly natural to say (with the exception that if you want it to be a contraction then it's "it apostrophe s", scallawag!).  You could also, as FumbleFingers suggested, just say "It's Brown".

Comment: @John: Your quite write their pronounced the same, but its somewhat discombobulating to see multiple "transcription errors" in the written form!

Comment: Nouns are best described with something like *it starts with an 'e' and ends with a 't' and has an 'm' somewhere in the middle*. If it's brown, it's probably an object.

Comment: @JohnLawler  Thanks for the chuckle at the uses of 'their', and FumbleFingers for the 'write'.

Comment: The first sentence " Its colour is brown' requires no apostrophy' as earlier indicated and that is because when you put an apostrophy,the grammer becomes wrong....
it becomes " It is colour is brown! How absurd.
IT'S Simply means It is.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences show redundancy. They are both grammatically correct, but it is not necessary to include "color".

Answer (score 0):

I would say that "it is brown in color" puts emphasis on the thing itself, while "its color is brown" emphasizes the color.

I would use the first in a context where one wouldn't necessarily describe an object's color (a book's cover, for example), but the second where a reference to color would be expected (like cloth).